# Selenium org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingHandler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8

So I am working with Java 8 attempting to create a simple Selenium project but getting errors about the loggingHandler. I have searched online for an answer ,but the only post I found the solutions was to down grade one of the dependencies. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AutoDrive {
    @Test
    public void findElementbyXpath() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/xxxx/dev/demo/src/main/resources/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http:www.google.com");

    //Maximizes the browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    for (String word : sampleList) {
        //find text field
        driver.findElement(By.name("typeahead-combine")).sendKeys(word);
        //wait for results
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    //close browser
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

I have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When trying to run I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingHandler
    at com.example.demo.AutoComplete.findElementbyXpath(AutoComplete.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Did you try creating a new project and doing the same?

Comment: Why do you need to add so many dependencies in POM file when you are using only basic functionalities of WebDriver. I think this should be enough for your work 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

You can change the version of selenium-api to 3.14.0.

[image]